# How do I create Messaging Level Users in IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I've set up IBM MQ using the container https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/mq/ . I would like to create users with messaging level permission as in https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS5K6E_9.1.0/com.ibm.mqa.doc/administering/ad00080_.htm . Can I just create this users in the container itself or do I need appliance. Could someone guide please

Comment: You can set up the queue manager to use LDAP for authentication and authorization.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for the response. Is it possible to imitate the same in IBM MQ cloud ?

Comment: I think you would either need an in cloud LDAP server or be able to communicate to a on prem LDAP, but I don't have any direct IBM cloud MQ experience.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll check further on this.